# How does Delegate.BeginInvoke signal the wait handle in the implementation of BeginRead in .NET 2.0?

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, asynchronous

The following is the implementation of the `System.IO.FileStream.BeginRead` method as it was in .NET 2.0.

As you can see, the implementation passes along the operation to the `ReadDelegate`'s `BeginInvoke` method.

However, before doing so, it initializes an `AutoResetEvent` and then calls `WaitOne` on it.

However, I do not see how the `ReadDelegate` could signal the `AutoResetEvent` as it would not have any reference to it.

Could you please explain how this works?

```
[HostProtection(SecurityAction.LinkDemand, ExternalThreading=true)]
public virtual IAsyncResult BeginRead(byte[] buffer, int offset, int count, AsyncCallback callback, object state)
{
    if (!this.CanRead)
    {
        __Error.ReadNotSupported();
    }
    Interlocked.Increment(ref this._asyncActiveCount);
    ReadDelegate delegate2 = new ReadDelegate(this.Read);
    if (this._asyncActiveEvent == null)
    {
        lock (this)
        {
            if (this._asyncActiveEvent == null)
            {
                this._asyncActiveEvent = new AutoResetEvent(true);
            }
        }
    }
    this._asyncActiveEvent.WaitOne();
    this._readDelegate = delegate2;
    return delegate2.BeginInvoke(buffer, offset, count, callback, state);
}
```

Comment: The `AutoResetEvent` is created in the signaled state right from the start (that's what that `true` is for), so the `.WaitOne()` immediately returns if the event was just created. That's half of the answer -- the other is explaining what the `.WaitOne()` is for if the event already exists (ensuring that only one read at a time can be happening?)

Comment: Is this source the result of decompilation?

Comment: @YacoubMassad Yes. I saw it in Reflector.

Comment: @JeroenMostert Another thing that confuses me is that many examples in the MSDN also set the initial state of the `AutoResetEvent` to true and still wait for it and then signal it while alluding to the fact that the wait blocks the current thread until the event is explicitly signaled. I am still confused about what the purpose of the `initialState` then is. What you're saying intuitively makes sense but the MSDN leaves me confused. Consider this example. See `event_1` in the example code: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.autoresetevent%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Comment: That sounds like it might be a second question. :-) However, you should put little stock in MSDN samples in general -- they are often trivial, confusing, incorrect or any combination of the three. This particular sample, while not wrong, is only intended to illustrate the behavior -- it does not represent a realistic use case. In any case, an `AutoResetEvent` that is created in the signaled state will *not* block on the first call to `.WaitOne()`. It will block on subsequent calls, until `.Set()` is called.

Comment: @JeroenMostert Thank you. As a practice, I always initialize my `AutoResetEvents` to `false` based on that good assumption.

Comment: Are you sure this is FileStream and not Stream.Read? I don't see any async IO here.

Comment: @usr You're right. My bad. I checked closely and it is from the `Stream` class instead. This method is called into by the `FileStream` class' `BeginRead` if the read operation was requested to run synchronously. I gleaned this bit of information by looking at the SSCLI 2.0 source files which I downloaded just now upon Hans Passant's suggestion in his answer below. I am at my wit's end. It looks like I don't understand anything now. This seems like an uphill climb. Thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: @JeroenMostert I think I cracked the bit about the `WaitOne` and the initial state of the `AutoResetEvent`. See my last third comment to Hans Passant's answer. :-)

Comment: @JeroenMostert Oh, I think you already said the same thing much earlier in one of your previous comments. :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The decompiler cannot help you retrieve the comments in the original source code.  Which is available for .NET 2.0 from the SSCLI20 distribution.  It reads like this:

```
       // To avoid a race with a stream's position pointer & generating race
       // conditions with internal buffer indexes in our own streams that
       // don't natively support async IO operations when there are multiple
       // async requests outstanding, we will block the application's main
       // thread if it does a second IO request until the first one completes.
       if (_asyncActiveEvent == null) {
           lock(this) {
               if (_asyncActiveEvent == null)
                   _asyncActiveEvent = new AutoResetEvent(true);
           }
       }
       bool r = _asyncActiveEvent.WaitOne();
       BCLDebug.Assert(r, "AutoResetEvent didn't get a signal when we called WaitOne!");

       BCLDebug.Assert(_readDelegate == null && _writeDelegate == null, 
           "Expected no other readers or writers!");
```

So if `_asyncActiveEvent` is null then there cannot be any other async I/O operation in flight so there isn't any point in blocking the operation.  Initializing the ARE to be set is thus quite intentional.  The WaitOne() call resets it again so calling BeginRead() a second time before the previous one is completed will block and avoid the race conditions.  EndRead() unblocks by setting it again.

The possible mental speed-bump is that the ARE is used backwards from its normal usage.  It is only set when nothing is going on.

Comment: Wow! Just wow! I am picking up new good habits just because of your wonderful answers. I will now read the source for the current version from referencesource.com and for previous versions by downloading their sources from the SSCLI distribution site. Thing is: I want to load it in Visual Studio on my machine and step through it and do dirty things with it, but I am scared. I don't know how to do that. I see a readmefirst.html and it says I need ActivePerl, an old priest and a young one before I should feel confident about this. I am scared. Am I stupid or something?

Comment: I just feel challenged. Every now and then I discover how incompetent I am.

Comment: And I just realized I still don't understand even the little bit of threading I thought I understood till now. I esp. don't understand how the `AutoResetEvent` behaves.

Comment: Judging by your answer, you seem to be implying that the signal state of the `AutoResetEvent` (or any other wait handle) is neutral. You could set it to `true` to begin with and that doesn't mean anything. When a thread signals the state, it just flips the state bit thus making the new value `false`? Am I following you correct? Also, I am confused when you say `WaitOne` resets it. Isn't `WaitOne` supposed to just passively wait till it is signaled?

Comment: Eureka! I kept re-reading that bit of code and I think the correct explanation has dawned upon me. The first thread that acquires the lock and initializes `_asyncActiveEvent`, the `AutoResetEvent` field, will not block on the `WaitOne` because the wait handle is already signaled, meaning no other thread is attempting to run this method just yet. Any other concurrent thread thereafter will find an already initialized wait handle and will block on the `WaitOne` call. Ah, yes. That seems to be it. Sanity has been restored. Everything I knew earlier is in consonance with this explanation.

Comment: Therefore, as you say, they use the ARE backwards but purposefully so. It's a clever thing they did. So, then wait handle states are not neutral. Signaled is `true` and otherwise `false` as my previous understanding was.

Comment: The next project is to load the SSCI 2.0 source in Visual Studio 2015. I see the **Building and Running Code** section is quite easy to understand though it might be a bit of a haggle to actually get it working. Rolls up sleeves!

Answer (score 0):

It appears that the `AutoResetEvent` I mention in the question is not used to signal the completion of the `ReadDelegate` as that is already delegated to the `BeginInvoke` method on delegate via a callback, but to ensure that the `EndRead` was called and thus maintain atomicity of the complete `BeginXXX` and `EndXXX` operation as one single unit.

This can be inferred from the code of the `EndRead` method of the same class.

```
public virtual int EndRead(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
{
    if (asyncResult == null)
    {
        throw new ArgumentNullException("asyncResult");
    }
    if (this._readDelegate == null)
    {
        throw new ArgumentException(Environment.GetResourceString("InvalidOperation_WrongAsyncResultOrEndReadCalledMultiple"));
    }
    int num = -1;
    try
    {
        num = this._readDelegate.EndInvoke(asyncResult);
    }
    finally
    {
        this._readDelegate = null;
        this._asyncActiveEvent.Set();
        this._CloseAsyncActiveEvent(Interlocked.Decrement(ref this._asyncActiveCount));
    }
    return num;
}
```

The `AutoResetEvent` is represented by the identifer `_asyncActiveEvent`, which is a class level instance variable.